# Delete record that does not exist in both columns

Tags: mysql

I need to delete record from **ent** table that does not exist in both column of **ent_id** or **ent_id_val** in table **value**

ent

```
+--------+
| ent_id |
+--------+
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      3 |
+--------+
```

value

```
+--------+------------+
| ent_id | ent_id_val |
+--------+------------+
|      1 |       NULL |
|   NULL |          2 |
+--------+------------+
```

The ent_id can be in either colum of ent_id and ent_id_val in value table.
In the example above, I want the record ent_id = 3 to be deleted.
Below is what I have attempt, it does delete some, but I wonder why it does not delete all completely ? I still have record in **ent** table that is not being used in **value** table.

```
DELETE e.* 
FROM ent e 
LEFT JOIN value v1 on e.ent_id = v1.ent_id 
LEFT JOIN value v2 on v2.ent_id_val = e.ent_id
WHERE v1.ent_id is null and v2.ent_id_val is null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE a  
FROM  ent a
      LEFT JOIN value b
         ON   a.ent_ID = b.ent_ID
      LEFT JOIN value c
         ON   a.ent_ID = c.ent_id_val
WHERE b.ent_ID IS NULL AND c.ent_id_val IS NULL;
```

- [**See SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3899e/1)

OR

```
DELETE a FROM ent a
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT ent_ID FROM value
            UNION
            SELECT ent_id_val AS ent_ID FROM value
        ) b ON a.ent_ID = b.ent_ID
WHERE   b.ent_ID IS NULL
```

- [**See SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcb06/1)

Comment: What a beautiful way of answering... Awesome. I was convinced to vote-up even before correctly understanding the question :) SQLFiddle is awesome as well :)

Comment: Yeah, sqlfiddle is awesome! :D

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work, my table is big, still running :D Do you know why my query not working perfectly ?

Comment: @William i bet you did not properly index your table. which query did you use by the way? can you post the schema of your table so i can see if you have an index or not.

Comment: can you post the result of this query `desc ent;` and `desc value;` please? thanks.

Comment: Hi, in my view, I did use index. I used the second query. Here it's https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35940459/schema.sql

Comment: oh i see it, both queries are running slow?

Comment: I only run the second query so far, cause I think the NOT IN is slower. The value table is big though, 12 million records. Now keep having Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: @William i think because of the subquery which stores it in a temporary table and perform full table scan. [SQLFiddle Demo (try this updated one)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3899e/1)

Comment: @William did you try  the link?

Comment: Hi, yes, that is the fastest only a few seconds. That query also back to my original query that I posted, but btw, it's my fault, when I check if there's any ent_id that is not deleted, I only check the column ent_id in value, but not ent_id_val. So actually the original query already working. Sorry for the inconveninence caused :D

Comment: I like to mark this as answered. But maybe it's better to update the answer to the original query ? Sorry for the trouble :D

Comment: Marked :D Thanks a lot, anyway your help has helped me find my fault :D